# Trying to get file name from fd using readlink in linux by intercepting file system call, but it is not working

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to get the filename/filepath from fd using readlink() but it does not give me anything. I don't understand why? Could someone please help me with this.? asm/unistd.h  file is also included in the original code.

```
asmlinkage size_t our_sys_write(int fd,char __user *buf,size_t count)

{
char fileinfo_buff[200], path[120],rdfilepath[100], temp_buff[200];
char filepath[100];
int ret;
ssize_t buf_sz=0;

memset(rdfilepath,0,100);

print_time(USER_TIME);                                    // Get Current Time

strcpy(fileinfo_buff,USER_TIME+1);                       // Store Time in Log Array

ret=get_username(USER_NAME);

if(ret < 0)
{                   
    //printk(KERN_ALERT "\n error in get_username in our_sys_read");
}
else
{
    strcat(fileinfo_buff,USER_NAME);
}

sprintf(filepath,"/proc/%u/fd",current->pid);

buf_sz =  original_readlink(filepath,rdfilepath,sizeof(rdfilepath));

rdfilepath[buf_sz] = '\0';

sprintf(temp_buff,"#WRITE#%d#%lu#",fd,count);             

//strcat(temp_buff,filepath);

strcat(fileinfo_buff,temp_buff);

strcat(fileinfo_buff,rdfilepath);

strcat(fileinfo_buff,"\n");

strcpy(path,"/home/y/output/");

strcat(path,log_filename);

if((USER_NAME[0]>='A' && USER_NAME[0]<='Z')||(USER_NAME[0]>='a' && USER_NAME[0] <='z'))
{
    write_file(fileinfo_buff,path);}
return original_write(fd,buf,count);}

/* some lines of code */
static int init(void){

/* some lines of code */
original_readlink=(void *)syscall_table[__NR_readlink];
/* some lines of code */

syscall_table[__NR_write]=our_sys_write;
}
```

I tried with

> > sprintf(filepath,"/proc/%u/fd/%d",current->pid,fd);

also. But still it gives me null value.
Can someone please help me with this or explain me why it is happening? Why I am not getting the filename?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the readlink(), but with your syscall hooking. Try to do this with the normal glibc readlink() call, and you will see, that it works.

The normal ls and such commands find the filename from the /proc//fd/ with this, too.

A strace output could help a lot. Especially if you compare this with the strace of some working tool which does the same (f.e. ls).

Comment: Thank you very much for replying...I tried it that way also but it was giving me this error : implicit declaration of function ‘readlink’.. even if I have included unistd.h file. What should be the problem?? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, but what I don't understand, why do you need kernel calls, if there are good and simple libc call for this? man 2 readlink! It is in unistd.h . And your sprintf seems correct.